# Load postgis database with PK from two fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatial-database

I have a PostGIS database having a Primary Key from two fields **id_cat** and **id_cdad**. When I load this database in QGIS in my computer under Linux there are no problem. I unmark "Select ID" and I can mark more than one field in the combo box of Primary Key because there are a checkbox that let me do that. (QGIS 2.12 under Linux Mint 17.0)

Now I want to install my database in a computer under window, but there aren't the checkboxes close to the name of fields, so I can't to mark more that one field for define the primary key.
(QGIS 2.10 under windows 7)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the QGIS version to 2.12 on computer under window and I can see and mark the checkboxes so I have solved my problem.